# Have multiple accpunts on the same provider in python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am currently using `python-social-auth` package for authenthication in my django site. I want users to be able to associate multiple social accounts to on django account. But if I call `social:begin` view when user is already logged in with account from the same provider, it does nothing and just logs in the old account. Is there a way to tell it to force adding of new account from that provider?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have ``'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email'`` and ``'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user'`` in your ``SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE`` settings?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the provider that you want to show the user the "select account" form again (when possible, since this is provider dependent), or ask the user to logout from the original account if it wants to add another association.

For example, with `google-oauth2` you can do it by adding this setting

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'prompt': 'select_account'
}
```

Google's API documentation lists the [supported values for `prompt`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#prompt).

You can also play with this other option:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'approval_prompt': 'force'
}
```